# Why do we have to update multiple widgets from one widget?

Tags: java, android, android-widget, android-broadcastreceiver

I have written just few widgets in android but one thing always made me curious. in the onUpdate() method we loop through all the widget ids and it says **there can be multiple widget active so update them all** . But why do we have to update other widget from one widget like this ?

```
override fun onUpdate(context: Context, appWidgetManager: AppWidgetManager, appWidgetIds: IntArray) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    for (appWidgetId in appWidgetIds) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId)
    }
}
```

Every widget has its own Broadcast reviever and each can run by itself. Why do we have to call update from another widget ?

Please take my question easily if this is a very simple logic.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you do not need to update a widget if it is registered as a broadcast receiver. You do need to if it is not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Every widget has its own Broadcast reviever

No, it does not.

First, an `AppWidgetProvider` class handles all app widgets provided by that provider. If the user creates several instances of that app widget (e.g., weather reports for several cities), all of them are updated by that single `AppWidgetProvider` class.

Second, an individual instance of `AppWidgetProvider` is used for a single `onUpdate()` call. This is because `AppWidgetProvider` is a subclass of `BroadcastReceiver`, `onUpdate()` is triggered by `onReceive()`, and a manifest-registered `BroadcastReceiver` gets a unique instance per `onReceive()` call.

Comment: Thank you for such a insightful paragraph.

Comment: Hey @CommonsWare, is there a way to update only a single widget (I have multiple instances as you mentioned) but what is the best way to separate the data)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56545567/update-single-widget

Comment: @Jeroen: Each app widget has an ID. If you pass that ID in your calls to `AppWidgetManager`, it will only update that specific app widget instance, not others.

Comment: @CommonsWare but how do I get this ID? when I use the code I posted in the link I put in my previous comment, I always get the same ID for all the widgets.

Comment: @Jeroen: "but how do I get this ID?" -- `onUpdate()` is passed an array of them, one ID per widget. "I always get the same ID for all the widgets" -- are you saying that there are N widgets and the array has only one element? Or are you saying that there are N widgets, and the array has N elements, but each element in the array is the same value?

Comment: @CommonsWare thank you, that was what I needed. I was using the wrong ID for all the widgets.